# Airflow dag for sql insert statements

Tags: airflow

I would need to create a DAG which would perform sql inserts into db tables based on a schema name.

DAG example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG, utils
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator



CONNECTION_ID = ...
WAREHOUSE = ...
DATABASE = ...
ROLE = ...

SQL_STRING = (
    "SELECT SCHEMA,TABLE FROM LOG_SCHEMA.LOG001;"
)

dag = DAG(
    'my_test',
    start_date=utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    default_args={'connection_id': CONNECTION_ID},
    catchup=False,
)

my_sql = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='my_sql',
    dag=dag,
    sql=SQL_STRING,
    warehouse=WAREHOUSE,
    database=DATABASE,
    role=ROLE,
)

my_sql
```

In my example output of my_sql is just schema name and table name. I would like to use this in order to perform inserts.
Example:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE SELELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE COL1=2;
```

I would import my variables with schema names and based on my needs select let's say schema TEST in order to execute inserts for all tables in this schema.

```
INSERT INTO TEST.TABLE001 SELELECT * FROM TEST.TABLE001 WHERE COL1=2;
INSERT INTO TEST.TABLE002 SELELECT * FROM TEST.TABLE002 WHERE COL1=2;
INSERT INTO TEST.TABLE003 SELELECT * FROM TEST.TABLE003 WHERE COL1=2;
```

Comment: Someone who can answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to achieve this:

- using Airflow: by creating a python task which read the result of the first query and prepares a new query you can execute in a separate `SnowflakeOperator` task.
- using snowflake and SQL: SQL support loop, where you can store the result in a cursor, then loop over the cursor records to call new statements (I am not sure about the syntax in snowflake, so maybe you need to fix it):

```
DECLARE
    c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT SCHEMA,TABLE FROM LOG_SCHEMA.LOG001;
    schema_col varchar;
    table_col varchar;
    sql varchar default 'INSERT INTO ?.? SELECT * FROM ?.? WHERE COL1=2';
BEGIN
  FOR record IN c1 DO
      schema_col := record.SCHEMA;
      table_col := record.TABLE;
      execute immediate :query using(schema_col, table_col, schema_col, table_col)
  END FOR;      
  RETURN 'End';
END;
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. I would like to try the first one. If I understand correctly I can use my output from my_sql and use some python function which will read data from let's say data frame or dictionary and perform inserts?

Comment: the python function transform the result of the first query and return a new SQL query which you can execute in a new `SnowflakeOperator` task, so python task dosen't interact with any external service, it just parse a string and produce a new string

Comment: could you please give me an example since I don't have expirience with Airflow. my_sql -> pythonoperater  -> snowflakeoperater?